# deviseで複数モデルを作成し、各々にomniauth-facebookを適用する

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

deviseを用いて複数モデル`(teacher.rb/student.rb)`を作成することはできました。
そして、それぞれに`omniauth-facebook`を用いて`omniauth`を実装したいのですが、deviseの`omniauthable`が競合してうまくいきません。
この場合、アプローチとしてどうするのが適切なのでしょうか。
3つめのモデル`omniuser.rb`などを作成してそこに処理を集中させる方法を考えたのですが、どう思いますか?
そのメソッドや参考になるサイトを教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score -1):

こちらに解決策が書いてあると思いますよ
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth-with-multiple-models

Comment: 回答分に解決策を書いてください。(最近ログインされてないみたいなので無意味だとは思いますが…)